# Remote Screen Sharing in realtime like SharedView, TeamViewer

Tags: windows, winapi

What technologies would I need to know to write an app like the now defunct Microsoft SharedView or something like TeamViewer?  Any way to do it with a browser and not need a client app?

I'm a .NET developer, but figure I'd need to know C++ or driver stuff?
How would you stream the users desktop to another user?  How do you even capture it in realtime?

I can imagine how you could take screenshots of the desktop and transfer them, but how do you capture live video of the screen of application and stream it to another user.

There are many apps that do this: Skype, GotoMeeting, TeamViewer, SharedView, Citrix, logmein, etc. but I'd like to write my own.

How would I get this to work on Windows, tablets, droids, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

The browser seems to be a good platform for this, but there are some limitations

1 - flash doesn't work at all on IOS, and is not widely available on android.

2- Webrtc works with chrome, firefox and opera on mac/pc/linux, and with firefox/chrome on android.  There's  librairies to use webrtc from an IOS native app(in objective C). Screen Sharing on the other hand only works with chrome (pc/mac/linux). There's a work in progress in firefox.

3- Installation of browser plugins will be hard if not impossible on various platforms, but it can open some possibility : on chrome and firefox  you can make them with javascript. For example a javascript extention can share a tab in chrome.

Using javascript you can stream from a desktop to any other desktop / android.